# keep carousel on same slide after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

so i have a bootstrap carousel on my page and i'm trying to change the content of the page depending on which slide in currently showed. i have the current slide index in a javascript variable but can't transfer the value to php. so i am now getting the value with GET but the php variable's value don't change unless i refresh the page, but when i do refresh the page the slides reset to the first one. 
how can i let the carousel stay on the same slide even after the page is refreshed? thank you

this is my carousel:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="8"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="9"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="10"></li>
</ol>


<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="images/wisp.png" alt="WISP" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/linkme.png" alt="linkme" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/zainent.png" alt="zain" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/tahadi.png" alt="tahadi" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/onelife.png" alt="onelife" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/alavina.png" alt="alavina" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/iha.png" alt="iha" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/runnuts.png" alt="runnuts" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/oliviafred.png" alt="oliviafred" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/bandicoot.png" alt="bandicoot" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="images/bassama.png" alt="bassama" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
</div>


<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" onclick="return chooseit()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>      
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" onclick="return chooseit()">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>     
</a>
```

and this is my script:

```
      function chooseit() {
var numbit = $('div.active').index() + 1;
history.pushState(null, null, '/work.php?id='+numbit);
}



$(function(){
        var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
        var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
        var clickCount = 0;

        itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

        //Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
        carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

        //Place the child elements to their original locations.
        refreshChildPosition();

        //Set the event handlers for buttons.
        $('.btnNext').click(function(){
            clickCount++;

            //Animate the slider to left as item width 
            carousel.finish().animate({
                left : '-='+itemWidth
            },300, function(){
                //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
            });
        });

        $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
            clickCount--;
            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
            lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
            lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);

            lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);             
            //Animate the slider to right as item width 
            carousel.finish().animate({
                left: '+='+itemWidth
            },300);
        });

        function refreshChildPosition(){
            carouselChild.each(function(){
                $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
            });
        }

        function refreshChildPositionNext(){
            carouselChild.each(function(){
                leftVal =  parseInt($(this).css('left'));
            });
        }
    });
```

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
var currentSlide = $('#myCarousel div.active').index();
sessionStorage.setItem('lastSlide', currentSlide);   
});
if(sessionStorage.lastSlide){
  $("#myCarousel").carousel(sessionStorage.lastSlide*1);
}
```

this worked perfectly for me !

Answer (score 2):

You could store the current slide number as a local variable.

`localStorage.setItem('slide', activeSlideNumber)`

Then when the document loads, check to see if the slide variable exists in storage as follows.

```
$(function() {
   var slide = localStorage.getItem('slide');
   if (slide === null) {
      // start from the top
   } else {
      // start from slide number in storage
   }
});
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try this?